How to pass Date and Time of last update from Sharepoint list to Power Apps
Does anyone know how to display date and time of last update on Power Apps?
My flow looks like : I pull data from Excel file to Sharepoint list every 1 hour by Power Automate.
My App on Power Apps is linked with Sharepoint List so whatever I do in PowerApps is visible on Sharepoint List. I have tried something like First(Sort(SharepointListName;Modified;SortOrder.Descending)).Modified but I don't think it solves the whole problem, wish to be able to display D&T of last update when new data has been downloaded to Sharepoint List only.
Please advise.

I wish to be able to display D&T of last update when new data has been downloaded to Sharepoint List only. How to exclude my manual changes in data from this label?  Last update should be the data and time of pulling the data from Excel only. My manual modifications in data should not count. IS it possible?

I am not sure if I understand your question (I mean, why did you ask, if you know the answer? :) ), but your code is correct. I reproduced on a dummy list and made a dummy app: 

I guess this logic will fail with a large data set, as it will give a delegation warning.
